# How to set up a parameterized Fixture to configure & reuse construction logic?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, xunit

The question is how to set up a parameterized Fixture?

```
using Xunit;

public class Fixture : IDisposable
{
    public Fixture(int param1, int param2)
    {
        // logic that depends on the value of the parameters
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

// How can the test supply the value of the parameters to 
// Fixture's constructor?
public class UnitTest : IUseFixture<Fixture>
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
    }

    public void SetFixture(Fixture data)
    {            
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where will you pass the arguments to the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand why to use `IUseFixture`, it is to provide data per [Testcase Class](http://xunitpatterns.com/Testcase%20Class.html). This means that the data will be shared among [Testcase Objects](http://xunitpatterns.com/Testcase%20Object.html) of the Testcase Class. In this sense, using a static field in the Testcase Class would be same as what you want.

```
public class UnitTest
{
    private static Fixture fixture = new Fixture(1, 2);

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree your solution achieve the same result, but IUseFixture is not in the picture.